# 1.4.5 ‎Theorem ‎of‎ ‎Murphy's ‎book

Tags: operator-theory, compact-operators

See 1.4.5 ‎Theorem ‎of‎ ‎Murphy's ‎book :‎ I ‎want ‎to ‎prove ‎that ‎if ‎‎$‎u$ be compact operator on ‎$‎X‎$ which is ‎Banach ‎space ‎and ‎‎$‎\lambda‎\in ‎‎\mathbb{C}‎\setminus\{0\}‎‎‎‎‎‎$‎, ‎then ‎‎$‎ker(u-‎\lambda‎)$ ‎is ‎finite-‎dimensional. ‎

But ‎in ‎proof :‎ ‎if ‎we ‎assume ‎that ‎‎$‎Z=‎ker(u-‎\lambda)‎$‎, ‎why ‎we ‎have ‎‎$‎u(Z)‎\subseteq Z‎$‎ and $u_Z$ is in $K(Z)$ ?

Comment: What are $u_Z$ and $K(Z)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Z = \ker(u - \lambda)$ we have $(u-\lambda)z = 0$, so $u(z) = \lambda z \in Z$ for all $z \in Z$.

The restriction of a compact operator $u$ to a closed invariant subspace is compact: if $z_n$ is a bounded sequence in $Z$ then there is a subsequence such that $u(z_{n_k})$ converges in $X$. Since $Z$ is closed and $u(z_{n_k}) \in Z$, this subsequence converges also in $Z$. Thus, the restriction $u_Z$ of $u$ to $Z$ is compact, so $u_Z \in K(Z)$.

On the other hand $u_Z = \lambda \cdot \operatorname{id}_Z \in K(Z)$ and since $\lambda \neq 0$ we have that $\operatorname{id}_Z$ is compact, which is only possible in finite-dimensional spaces.